# How can I calculate the probability that a particular value belongs to a cluster in a list of continuous values?

Tags: python, clustering

I have a list of observed times for multiple events that fall into clusters. Here is an example distplot with kernel density estimate:
[image]

How can I calculate the probability that a particular observation belongs to a particularly cluster, or is an outlier or otherwise unique event?

EDIT 2022-01-19_12:38
In response to comments here is some more context. The data is from metabolomic analysis by LC-MS/MS, so each feature has an associated mass spectrum. The processing is meant to produce a single feature to represent commonly observed features in dozens of analyses. Unfortunately it often produces artifactual replicates, so features that are close in time and have similar mass spectra. I have calculated similarities between their spectra, so maybe I should use this data to cluster them by both MS similarity and retention time.

Comment: You need more assumptions, because such probabilities can be computed only when you assume some prior probabilities to begin with.

Comment: You need more data because there are not enough values to properly define significantly distinct individual density function populations for a significant mixture model, alternatively, as @whuber says, one could make more assumptions, but unless those assumptions are physically deterministic, and/or testable, the danger in that would be to produce fantastic results.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have added some context.

Comment: Please explain how sample collection and preparation and LC-MS config affect the deconvolution of the data into unique features?